# My flutter application user interface cannot be displayed on some Windows PCs

Tags: windows, flutter, user-interface, display

I found that this issue is caused by the power policy of Windows. When my laptop is unplugged and the power mode is in balanced mode, the client user interface will not be displayed when I restart it. When I set the power mode to high-performance mode, the client user interface will display when I restart it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PZLH.png)
How should I set the user interface to display in any power mode in the client code?